# regex basic line return

Tags: regex, linux

I have a log file containing the following lines:

```
bbb authentication login ddd  
aaa authentication logout abc  
aaa authentication login ffff   
aaa authentication login nnnnn
```

I want to return the whole line by matching one word.

For example to type "nnnnn" in regex and get the whole line for that keyword.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to return this line **aaa authentication login nnnnn** by one regex?

Answer (score 0):

First, note that there is not regex needed for your case.

You may take a look to the manual of `grep` command:

> NAME
>          grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep - print lines matching a pattern

For your specific example, you have to execute:

```
grep nnnnn <filename>
```